# How to hide background label from google map while using custom tile overlay

Tags: android-maps-v2

I am developing android map application with custom tile overlay for indoor building. My requirement is to add custom tile only on building and rest of the map should visible to user just like a google map(Map type should be normal i.e.
**map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);**). I have achieve what i was expecting, except i am not able to hide the background label. Google default label are showing on top of the my custom tile. Can somebody please tell me how can we put tile above the google tile and prevent default label from getting appear.

[Map image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWWpj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

with the current implementation of google maps it is not possible because labels are drawn with a greater Z index from maps api.

You are a bit lucky that they introduced Maps Styling:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/hiding-features

With a bit of tests and luck you can get the style you need that hides labels

A quick test lead me to this:
https://snazzymaps.com/style/209830/no-labels

PS: Can take up to 48hours for the link to be available, but should already be there!